# "invalid number exception: invalid number: not a valid number string" when call a stored procedure

Tags: sql, hana

I have a small stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "XYZ"."TEST" (
    IN KKK_ID NVARCHAR(12),
    IN START_DATE SECONDDATE, 
    IN END_DATE SECONDDATE,
    IN INTER INTEGER
)
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "DATES") AS "INDEXX"
    FROM "XYZ::DATA"
    WHERE
        "DATES" >= :START_DATE
        AND
        "DATES" <= :END_DATE
        AND
        "ID" = :KKK_ID
    ORDER BY "DATES";
```

When I try to call this procedure, I'm getting this error message:

```
CALL "XYZ"."TEST"('DE666', '2014-01-01', '2015-12-31', 2234);
```

> invalid number exception: invalid number: not a valid number string 'DE666'

But the 'D666' looks like a string - at least for me. Whats wrong here?

PS: the `id` is not a reserved word.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Actually, this was just an attempt to pinpoint the error.
If I change it back to `seconddate`or something else the error message is the same..

Comment: @GurwinderSingh,
nope, it is a `varchar(33)` type

Comment: The error message is saying that the string `DE666` is not a valid number, not that it's not a string. As for why it's trying to treat it as a number, I don't know. Presumably `"XYZ::DATA"."ID"` is a number?

Comment: @melpomene as I said before, the column is of type String/NVARCHAR  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the error message doesn't say "'*DE666' is not a valid string.*" What it says is "'DE666' is not a valid **number** string". That means that to HANA this string is not a valid string representation of a number. 
Valid representations are those that can be converted into a number, e.g. '1', '2.34', '4,323,252.2354' etc. 
That 'DE' bit in your string simply doesn't make sense to the data type conversion routine.

So, that's about the error message.
The second point you made is that the base column for "ID" is actually a NVARCHAR column, so that it's not quite clear, why there is a type conversion in the first place. In my experience, this sort of conversions occurs due to implicit conversions, that have not been minded by the developer. E.g. the return type definition of "XYZ::DATA" (could be a view or a table function) might have been declared as a number. This is easy to overlook and not uncommon.

If you cannot find such a wrong type declaration, then place post all DDL to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error while running a long query.

The part where the error occurred was something like

```
where m.member = 'id'
```

So I just changed it to

```
where m.member like 'id%'
```

and voila! It worked! That error didn't show up anymore.

I still have no idea the reason behind why the error came in the first place or how this solved the problem, but hey, as long as the solution works.

Just posting this in case others like me encounter this issue in the future.